# AWS CLI Usage for IAM Users

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I created a IAM Admin user for my myself as per the best practices. The way I have done is by creating a Role attach **AdminAccess** and assigning it to a UserGroup. My IAM User is added to this group. On console, I could easily switch to this role and perform all Admin actions.

However, while using CLI, it seems like I could not switch to this AdminRole and only getting **AccessDenied** for everything I tried except for `aws iam list-users`

I have temporarily fixed this by configuring the cli with root credentials but this is still not the best solution for me.

Any idea how to address this?

Using on Windows 11 and CLI Version 2.7.0

***UPDATE***

[Template used to create my IAM roles and groups](https://github.com/S-Polimetla/cloud-formation-templates/blob/master/iam/dev-account-roles.yaml)

Users were created manually via console and assigned to respective groups. The user I am using belongs to all the 3 groups given, AllUsersGroup, DeveloperGroup, AdminGroup

Comment: Please share the given permission to the group. If the user/group has granted `AdministratorAccess` permission, then the user should be able to access any AWS resources via cli and console.

Comment: @HaeyoonJ. See my update

Comment: Could you share how you have configured your cli as well? (DON'T INCLUDE THE KEYS OR SECRETS :))

Comment: also, if you wish to find out who you are: aws sts get-caller-identity is very helpful for that (equivalent to aws whoami!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand, you have an IAM User that has credentials and that IAM User has permission to assume an Admin role. So, in the awscli configuration file (~/.aws/config) you need two sets of credentials: one for the IAM User and the other for the role, for example:

```
[profile sriharsha]
aws_access_key_id = xxx
aws_secret_access_key = yyy
region = us-east-1

[profile admin]
region = us-east-1
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/my-admin-role
source_profile=sriharsha
```

You can then use the awscli with the relevant set of credentials, for example:

1. aws s3 ls --profile sriharsha
2. aws iam list-users --profile admin

Comment: I noticed that this works only when I remove the Condition from the trust policy. Is there a way to do this and keep the condition https://github.com/S-Polimetla/cloud-formation-templates/blob/master/iam/dev-account-roles.yaml#L63

Comment: Else it fails with " failed to assume role "

Comment: Is there a way to keep the condition and use the profile?

Comment: Your [policy](https://github.com/S-Polimetla/cloud-formation-templates/blob/master/iam/dev-account-roles.yaml#L63) states that the role requires MFA. See [How do I use an MFA token to authenticate access to my AWS resources through the AWS CLI?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/)